# inconsistent dead code elimintation of mathematical functions

Tags: c++, c++14

In the following example, the elimination of unused code is performed for `sin()` but not for `pow()`. I was wondering why. Tried gcc and clang.

Here is some more details about this example, which is otherwise mostly code.
The code contains a loop over an integer from which a floating point number is computed.
The number is passed to a mathematical function: either `pow()` or `sin()`
depending on which macros are defined.
If macro `USE` is defined, the sum of all returned values is accumulated in another variable which is then copied to a volatile variable to prevent the optimizer from removing the code entirely.

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
  std::chrono::steady_clock clock;
  auto start = clock.now();

  double s = 0;
  const size_t count = 1 << 27;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    const double x = double(i) / count;
    double a = 0;
#ifdef POW
    a = std::pow(x, 0.5);
#endif
#ifdef SIN
    a = std::sin(x);
#endif
#ifdef USE
    s += a;
#endif
  }

  auto stop = clock.now();
  printf(
      "%.0f ms\n", std::chrono::duration<double>(stop - start).count() * 1e3);

  volatile double a = s;
  (void)a;
}
```

As seen from the output, the computation of `sin()` is completely eliminated if the results are unused. This is not the case for `pow()` since the execution time does not decrease.
I normally observe this if the call may return a NaN (`log(-x)` but not `log(+x)`).

```
# g++ 10.2.0
g++ -std=c++14 -O3 -DPOW main.cpp -o main && ./main
3064 ms
g++ -std=c++14 -O3 -DPOW -DUSE main.cpp -o main && ./main
3172 ms

g++ -std=c++14 -O3 -DSIN main.cpp -o main && ./main
0 ms
g++ -std=c++14 -O3 -DSIN -DUSE main.cpp -o main && ./main
1391 ms
```

```
# clang++ 11.0.1
clang++ -std=c++14 -O3 -DPOW main.cpp -o main && ./main
3288 ms
clang++ -std=c++14 -O3 -DPOW -DUSE main.cpp -o main && ./main
3351 ms

clang++ -std=c++14 -O3 -DSIN main.cpp -o main && ./main
177 ms
clang++ -std=c++14 -O3 -DSIN -DUSE main.cpp -o main && ./main
1524 ms
```

Comment: If you compile with `gcc -ffast-math ...`, you get `0ms` ! The point is that `-ffast-math` flag allows optimizations that do not preserve strict IEEE compliance. In particular, it makes the assumption that all math is finite, which means that no checks for `NaN`is performed

Comment: `-ffast-math` is heavy-handed, I think `-fno-math-errno`, should reduce most of the time difference.

Comment: thanks, `-fno-math-errno` is enough

Comment: @divfree note that if you update to C++17, you can avoid the preprocessor ifdef and use `constexpr if`, to the same effect.